# Linked List in C++, Outputting long values

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm working on linked List this time around. I'm yet to grasp the concept of memory allocation, etc. I was given a task to perform this linked list application that will add and remove a node. Both these functions will place the node on the TAIL. After that, i must display the list of nodes in a forward and backward order. I managed to get the forward and backward order in place. However, after removing a few nodes, the forward order displays the new nodes but the backward order seems to display more than necessary. Any idea why i'm getting more values than needed when going backwards? I'm assuming it has to do with Memory Allocation, hence why i'm having this issue.

As instructed by our professor, we are only allowed to change *list.cpp*. nothing more. 
Here is the console output:

```
 //Application crashes, when trying to remove the last node, WHY?
```

> Printing in Ascending Order (forward):
>
> 3 10 1 7 9 12
>
> Printing in Descending Order (backward):
>
> 12 9 7 1 10 3

This time it completely crashes the application when i include remove(12) which is the last node?

Here is the code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "list.cpp"

int main()
{
  LinkedList aList;

  aList.add(3);
  aList.add(10);
  aList.add(1);
  aList.add(7);
  aList.add(9);
  aList.add(12);
  aList.printAscending();
  aList.printDescending();
  aList.remove(3);
  aList.remove(1);
  aList.remove(7);
  aList.remove(12); //Application crashes here.
  aList.printAscending();
  aList.printDescending();

  return 0;
}
```

**list.h**

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class LinkedList
{
private:
  struct Node
  {
    int data; //store actual data value
    Node * next; //contains the address of next node.
    Node * prev;
  };
  Node * head, * tail;
public:
  LinkedList();
  ~LinkedList();
  bool add(int val); // You may add nodes to the head or tail.
  bool remove(int val);
  void printAscending() const;  // print the list in forward order.
  void printDescending() const; // print the list in reverse order.
};
```

The main issue is here:
list.cpp

```
#include "list.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList(){
  head = NULL;  //Head should always point to the first node.
  tail = NULL;  
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList(){
  delete head;
  delete tail;
}

bool LinkedList::add(int val){
  Node * newNode = new Node; //Creating a temp node struct pointer
  newNode->data = val; //setting the val parameter = to the tempNode data
  newNode->next = NULL; 
  newNode->prev = NULL;

  if(head == NULL && tail == NULL){ 
    head = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
  }else{
    newNode->prev = tail;
    tail->next = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
    newNode = NULL;
  }
  return true;
}

bool LinkedList::remove(int val){
  Node * newNode = head;
  Node * newPrev = NULL;
  Node * newNext = NULL;

  if(newNode == NULL)
    std::cout << "There are no Nodes to remove. Try adding some!" << std::endl;

  if(newNode->data == val){
    if(newNode != NULL){
        head = head->next;
        head->prev = NULL;
        delete newNode;
    }
  }else{
    while(newNode != NULL && newNode->data != val){
        newNode = newNode->next;
    }
    if(newNode != NULL){
        newNext = newNode->next;
        newPrev = newNode->prev;
        newNext->prev = newPrev;
        newPrev->next = newNext;
        delete newNode;
    }else{          
        newPrev = newNode->prev;
        delete newNode; 
        newPrev->next = NULL;

    }
  }
  return true;
}

void LinkedList::printAscending() const{
  std::cout << "Printing in Ascending Order (forward):" << std::endl;
  Node * newNode = new Node;
  newNode = head;
  while(newNode != NULL){
    std::cout << newNode->data << " ";
    newNode = newNode->next;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
void LinkedList::printDescending() const{
  std::cout << "Printing in Descending Order (backward):" << std::endl;
  Node * newNode = new Node;
  newNode = tail;
  while(newNode != NULL){
    std::cout << newNode->data << " ";
    newNode = newNode->prev;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Not sure i'f im allowed to link other sites, but here are the sources i've been looking at, credit to them:
 1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7OoiXJCD_E
 2. http://www.cprogramming.com/c++book/

Comment: You should reread  and debug you code, it has tons if issues, for example you allocate nodes and then immediately overwrite pointer creating a memory leak `Node * newNode = new Node;
  newNode = tail;`

Comment: @VTT i've been watching many tutorials and reading documents that utilize that specific way of writing code. I did encounter a few post in stackoverflow stating the same thing. Should i transition over to just creating a pointer?Node * newNode;

Comment: You should just create and initialize it at one step `Node * newNode = tail;` or (modern way) `auto newNode{tail};` Also you should carefully name variables, this `newNode` is not really new, it is just a pointer to iterate over nodes, so a better name for it would be some generic `p_node`.

Answer (score 0):

You delete your nodes, but you don't unlink them from the chain.

In your remove method, if you delete a node, make the prev of it's next point to its prev. Make the next of its prev point to its next. And make the appropriate adaptations at head and tail.

Since you only do a delete, the memory of your removed node is reclaimed by the system and used for something else entirely, which gives you a "random" value if you interpret it as a node.

By the way, don't call your method remove, unless you really only remove, so not delete, the node.

There may be additional references to the node elsewhere in your program.
The mere fact that the node is in your list, doesn't make the list the owner of your node, although through your way of programming this you made it impossible for a node to be in multiple lists. But still a different variable may hold its address. You should probably call your method removeAndDelete or something like that.

[EDIT]
Harun is right, you do unlink from the next chain. Only the prev you forget.

Comment: To expand on that, you do remove them from the 'next' chain, but not from the 'prev' chain, which is why you get different answers depending on the direction you move.

Comment: @Harun , i didn't try to unlink from the 'prev' chain since i'm assuming i'm moving from Left to right (traversing the list). However, now that i think about it, for the backward order function i need to traverse from TAIL to HEAD. Any more suggestions, i'm still pretty confused on what exactly im missing?